# Ubuntu 17.10 wifi router randomly drops

Tags: networking, wireless

Sometimes my wifi just drops for no reason. The laptop is just on for 5 or 10 minutes so there's no overheating or waking up from hibernation or anything.
When the wifi drops, in settings, it shows:

> Wi-Fi router not found

and the laptop flips into airplane mode all by itself.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:8257]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Do you have the same problem? How did you fix it?

Comment: "and my laptop is on Airplane mode." Are you saying that the laptop flips into airplane mode all by itself with no other actions by you? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes. That's what happened. I'll edit my question. Thank you for the question.

Comment: Reboot so that the wireless is working and run: `lsmod | grep wmi`. Then let it drop and let the laptop flip into airplane mode by itself and run the command again. Post the before and after as an edit to your question so we may compare the results.